# How to add html image in to velocity template file to send email?

Tags: java, velocity

I include this in my velocity file. but it is not working,

```
< img src="cid:src/resources/imageContent.jpg" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.  We do not understand your question at all.

Comment: i have answered similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489968/how-can-i-display-image-in-velocity-template/64754819#64754819

Comment: i have answer similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489968/how-can-i-display-image-in-velocity-template/64754819#64754819

Comment: i have answer this here - [How can I display image in velocity template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489968/how-can-i-display-image-in-velocity-template/64754819#64754819)

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the guide [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html).

For example, try this in your Velocity template file:

```
<img src = "cid:${cid}" alt = "Foo">
```

And in your Java code, try:

```
URL url = new URL("image.png");
String cid = email.embed(url, "Foo");
Map model = new HashMap();
model.put("cid", cid);
```

Comment: How can I do it using JavaMail with Velocity ?

Answer (score 1):

When your server is running you can get path till server from `request.getContexPath();`

So here you just need to provide rest path of the image. I have done this for my demo application like this.

```
 <img border="0" alt="Test" src="${projectPath}/images/logo.jpg"/></a></td>
```

Now you have to set value of projectPath to your projectPath which you can get by `request.getContexPath();`

Now create one Map in which you have to add Key which will keyword that you have used in .vm file. For this example, we have used projectPath.

```
 Map map = new HashMap<>();
 map.add("projectPath",request.getContexPath());
 map.add() // other value that you want to replace in vm file
```

After that create instance of VelocityContext load this map with constructor argument like this

```
 VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(map);
```